# How to test private functions in self-executing anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, qunit

```
var cls = (function() {
    function private() {
        return 'private';
    }
    return {
        public: function() {
            console.log(private());
            return 'public';
        }
    }
})();

QUnit.test('public test', function(assert) {
    assert.ok(cls.public() === 'public');
});

QUnit.test('private test', function(assert) {    
    assert.ok('How to access to the cls.private ?' === 'private');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ampfn13u/2/)

Function `private()` is accessible only in `cls` scope.

How to test it ?

As it seems to me, the only option is define it as public

```
return {
    _private: function() {
        return 'private';
    }
}
```

In that case, it will callable, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: You should test interfaces not implementations.

Comment: Don't test your private methods.

Comment: Your tests should represent usage of your public interfaces. Test the public interface that uses the private function.

Comment: if `private` is a "fat" function and I need to sure of its operability ? Maybe exists any reflection library ?

Comment: @cetver: What is a fat function?

Comment: @FelixKling Filled with bad code, inherited

Comment: There is no "Reflection" in JavaScript. You would have to read the source file, strip out the IIFE, and capture that function... but this would result in terrible side effects (read: not worth it). The others are correct here, you test your interface, which will in turn test your private functions.